# How do I install WordPress.org?

Tags: software-installation, php, wordpress

I learnt recently that the WordPress software in the Software Centre is WordPress.com, I want WordPress.org as it's more feature-full. I have downloaded the zip file and extracted its contents but it's all in PHP format. I looked at the readme file and it said to open the php install file in my web browser (which for me is Google Chrome) but whenever I do this it just re-downloads this file in the /home/fusion809/Downloads folder.

It says in the readme:

```
If for some reason this doesn’t work, don’t worry. It doesn’t work on all web hosts. 
Open up wp-config-sample.php with a text editor like WordPad or similar and fill in your database connection details.
Save the file as wp-config.php and upload it.
Open wp-admin/install.php in your browser.
```

I have no idea how to fill in the database connection details.

Comment: Look at this [How To Install Wordpress on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: When I ran `CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` in mySQL I got this output: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1`

Comment: I also got an error in the previous line: ` CREATE DATABASE wordpress;` too: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE wordpress' at line 1`

Comment: I'm a total noob when it comes to these things so I need better explanations (step-by-step command-line instructions would be helpful) than this one you showed me.

Comment: This the output I got: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` executing the first command line on this page.

Comment: You use a wrong password! Did you follow this before installing wordpress [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 14.04](https://digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) ?

Comment: No, I used my password. I use the same password for everything on my PC, so that can't be it.

Comment: I had to click "ignore" to this error. As it kept on asking me to retry I did and it didn't work. All these how-tos are piling up it seems, I just want some straight command line code to copy and paste into terminal.

Comment: What happened to that comment of yours with the link to myphysadmin on digitalocean or w/e it was as it seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment at the moment, but in simple terms, the main focus here should be to fix the mysql password, `sudo service mysql stop`, 
run the command `nano password` to invoke the nano editor, paste the following text substituting with the new password

```
    UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then save the file (CTRL-X, save the file), now start mysqld with the created file

```
    sudo mysqld --initfile=`pwd`/password
```

this will reset the mysql password, you may want to run `sudo killall mysqld; sudo service mysql start`

I'd then suggest using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress in order to install wordpress. It isn't a production ready environment, but will suffice for testing.

carry on if you actually want a "proper" install;
We are now going to start the installing process. I'm going to assume that you're running  ubuntu 14.04, and that you have nothing else on your webserver. (earlier versions will probably be the exact same, however replace /var/www/html with /var/www)

`sudo -s` This will run all commands as root, be wary of what you type!

okay, first we need mod_rewrite, apache2 comes bundled with it, however it is disabled by default!

`a2enmod rewrite; service apache2 restart;`

next,
cd into the web root folder
`cd /var/www/html`

`wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz`
`tar -vxaf latest.tar.gz`
`mv wordpress/* ./`
`rmdir wordpress`

We've just downloaded all of the relevant files required, and moved them into the correct place, next let's allow www-data (the user account for the web-server to modify files)

`chown -R www-data:www-data ./`

Next, let's allow .htaccess files,
`nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
and change the `AllowOverride` line to read `Allowoverride All`.

you should then be able to login to your webserver and setup the wordpress install.

Comment: How and where do I create the text file? If you can't comment then just edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Just create the text file in your current directory, that should work. pwd is used to get the current working directory, and thus shouldn't matter where the file is, as long as you run the commmand to start mysqld in the same directory as you created the file in.

Comment: So is the nano password part of the text file? If so I'd like to suggest you edit it accordingly, as the way it is now it's a little confusing.

Comment: This what output I get from mysqld line `140525  4:10:21 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140525  4:10:21 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/fusion809-Vostro-3500.lower-test
140525  4:10:21 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/fusion809-Vostro-3500.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
140525  4:10:21 [ERROR] Aborting

140525  4:10:21 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete`

Comment: `nano password` was the command to invoke nano with the correct filename.
You may have to run the mysqld command as root (just prepend `sudo` to the command)